# The Fortify add-in for Visual Studio did not execute

Tags: visual-studio-2015, fortify

I'm trying to run Fortify with my Visual-studio 2015 solution and it gives me this error always. This is the command I have used.

`sourceanalyzer -b MY_NAME -Xmx20g -debug -logfile MY_NAME_trans.log devenv mySolution.sln /BUILD "Debug" >> U:\Source\Solutions\Debug_log.txt`

Someone tere to help?

```
[2015-10-19 21:05:35.973 com.fortify.sca.util.compilers.DevenvNetAdapter.runCompiler() Thread-13 Master FINE]
Running compiler command: cmd /S /C "devenv mySolution.sln /BUILD"
[2015-10-19 21:06:05.302 com.fortify.sca.util.compilers.DevenvNetAdapter.runCompiler() Thread-13 Master SEVERE 1442]
The Fortify add-in for Visual Studio did not execute; therefore, no files were translated. Ensure that the Fortify add-in
is installed. If you are running Visual Studio 2005 SP1, you must also install the hotfix indicated by KB934517.
[2015-10-19 21:06:05.676 com.fortify.frontend.translator.dotnet.DotNetRegistryEntries.<clinit>() Thread-13 Master FINE]
Visual Studio install: null
CLR version: null
[2015-10-19 21:06:05.739 com.fortify.sca.frontend.FrontEndSession.runFrontEnd() Thread-13 Master INFO]
Front End complete
[2015-10-19 21:06:05.739 com.fortify.sca.metadata.BuildSession.storeIncrement() Thread-13 Master FINE]
Nothing to store.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick response. I ran

```
sourceanalyzer -b CAPS1 MSBuild "C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\CAPS1.sln"
```

and got the results below which didn't solve my original problem. I'm still not able to analyze my solution code through visual studio

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.6.81.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel    build,
please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 11/10/15 4:54:29 PM.
MSBuild: Project C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\CAPS1.sln  started, setting project root as C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main
Project "C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\CAPS1.sln" on node  1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
MSBuild: Project C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\Web\Web.vbproj started, setting project root as C:\Projects\CorpIT- FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\Web
Project "C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\CAPS1.sln" (1) is building "C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\Web\Web.vbproj" (2) on  node 1
(default targets).
CoreResGen:
No resources are out of date with respect to their source files. Skipping  resource generation.
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all   output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with  respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
Web -> C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\Web\bin\Web.dll
MSBuild: Project C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1 \Main\Web\Web.vbproj finished, setting project root as C:\Projects\CorpIT-   FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\Web
Done Building Project "C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\Web\Web.vbproj" (default targets).
MSBuild: Project C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main\CAPS1.sln  finished, setting project root as C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1\Main
Done Building Project "C:\Projects\CorpIT-FSSTax\AuditCAPS\CAPS1 \Main\CAPS1.sln"
 (default targets).

Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.57
```

Comment: came across this error   vs2019  -[error]: The Fortify add-in for Visual Studio did not execute; therefore, no files were translated. Ensure that the Fortify add-in is installed.